# What is the opposite to filter/filtering in search

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I have multiple search criteria, for example *country* and *city*.

To filter *(exclude results not matching the criteria)*, I can do: *country=xxx AND city=xxx*. But I can also do: *country=xxx OR city=xxx*. So how would you call the operation that is not excluding the results but instead broaden them? Is there some fitting verb for it like *filter*?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Accepted answer is probably easier to understand to any web user. However, for anybody interested, the more technical version of answer is: **filter** vs. **join** or **combine**.

Thanks again all for help!

Comment: _Inclusion Filter or Parameters_ :)

Comment: Yeah, perhaps `Add filter` and as opposite `Add parameter` could work... But I would still prefer some more self-explanatory term than parameter and in best case a verb.

Comment: I'm not certain whether you want an ordinary English word or a technical term. In any case I would say that by using 'OR' you **widen** the results.  Is that the sort of answer you are looking for?

Comment: Anything is good, as long as it describes the operation. *Widen* is not bad, wasn't sure if broaden, expand, extend or widen is the right word in this context:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Expand***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expand) is used when you try to increase the number of search results as it means:

> To increase the extent, number, volume or scope of (something).

[***Narrow***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narrow) is used when you try to decrease it.

> To reduce in width or extent; to contract. "We need to narrow the
>   search."

This [link](http://erwin-knowledgebase.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=517) shows how these 2 verbs are used.

"Expand or narrow your search using these examples"

Comment: Oh, great! This takes away the word *filter* completely, and takes us from technical language to normal human world.

Comment: @lp1051 "filter" can mean a lot of things, especially in technology fields.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

> **encompass**
>
> : include comprehensively

[OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/encompass)

Comment: Thanks for the idea and link. I don't like encompass so much, but it brought to me **combine**, which might be actually what I was looking for:)

Answer (score 1):

**Merge** is widely used in computer science for this type of operations that consist in "combining" 2 datasets by including in the result the items of both sets.

Comment: The problem is that there are different kinds of merge. Depending on the implementation, if you merge `city=xxx` with `city=yyy` you can get only `city=yyy` (if you're merging based on the field/key name). That's why I think **merge** is not so clear.

Comment: @lp1051 - The main connotation of merge is to "join together" what essentially covers a union operation.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I'm deformed from programming languages. But both "union" and "merge" behaves differently in different languages, and as said it often depends on custom implementation. For this inconsistency, I don't like merge or union. For this reason *combine* seems to work better. But maybe I'm just not aware of inconsistencies that *combine* has:)

Comment: @lp1051 - I hesitated to propose "join" because in SQL you may use both "INNER JOIN" (intersection) and "OUTER JOIN" (union). But, being also a professional developer, I  have not the same concern with the verb "merge", even if in some cases we may use merge for other operations that a simple union.

Comment: "join" actually works for me as well, thanks! I will accept the expand/narrow combo, but include your suggestion in technical alternative of accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen "unfilter", which is meaningful and obvious though a recent invention (and buried under brand names in search). "Remove filter" is better in many ways but takes up more screen space.

Alternatively having a "filter on/off" toggle would get round the question. Contrasting "filter" and "all (search) results" would have a similar effect.

Comment: "unfilter" is fun:) But I'm looking for word that stands beside *filter* so you can apply either *filter* or *the word I'm looking for*. Then you can toggle both *filter* and *the word I'm looking for*, not just *filter*.